# form should not appear after the 30 button_click

Tags: c#

**strong text**I Have a doubt

i have created an application in VS2010 for windows application

i have used form1 in form1 i used a button, onclicking on to the button it will load a second form ie.. form2 in which image is added

the overall situation is when i execute the application i'll get form1 and by clicking on the button(which is in form1) it will display the form2 (means it will display the image in the form2)

i want to code in such a way that

for the first time when i click the button the form2 will appear than i'll close the form2

### then again when i click the button for the second time the form2 will appear than i'll close the form2

### ---

### ---

---

like for the 30th time when i click the button the form2 will appear than i'll close the form2

but the confusion here is

when i click the button for the 31th time the form2 should not appear what ever it may be the form2 should never display again

i am getting totally confused how to do this please help me

please guide me with the code please

Comment: You can use a static counter variable in program and check how many times you want to allow.

Answer (score 1):

Create a counter as an [instance variable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173118.aspx) in Form1:

```
private int counter = 0;
```

Whenever you open Form2, increase the counter, i.e., add `counter++` to the code passage that opens your Form2 window:

```
...
counter++;
var form2 = new Form2();
form2.ShowDialog();
...
```

To prevent showing the form the 31-th time, add a check:

```
...
if (counter < 30) {
    counter++;
    var form2 = new Form2();
    form2.ShowDialog();
} else {
    MessageBox.Show("Sorry, Form2 has already been opened 30 times.");
}
...
```

Note: If Form1 is opened more than once, you might need to make `counter` static.

Answer (score 0):

You are coding winform application so you can just declare a

```
static int count;
```

And do the check each time button been click

```
if(++count <= 30)
{
    //show it
}
else
{
    //Do something else
}
```